# Atom tree view does not show all the files in the folder

Tags: treeview, atom-editor

When opening a local project in ATOM IDE, I find that there are missing files. I first thought it was due .gitignore. But deleting it didn't solve the issue. Is there anything I am missing?

Below are my local folder files and the project open in Atom IDE:

**Local folder files:**

[image: The files in my project folder]

**Project opened in ATOM IDE:** missing files are *wallpaper.jpeg*, *Deewar.jpg* and *Style.css*

[image: The files in my Atom editor]

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue. I changed the settings of the tree-view package (go to "Atom" tab, "Preferences" - "Packages" and search for tree-view): turned off "Hide VCS ignored files".